# how can i call custom adapter from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show an `ArrayList` in `ListView` using a `RecyclerView`. But its giving me error an in `onPostExecute` method when I pass the `ArrayList` and the `Context`.

My code is as follows,

```
class LoadAlltimeTable extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONHttpClient jsonHttpClient = new JSONHttpClient();
        UserModel[] user = jsonHttpClient.Get(ServiceUrl.TiMETABLE, nameValuePairs, UserModel[].class);

        if (user.length > 0) {
            arrayList= new ArrayList<UserModel>();
            for (UserModel product : user) {
                final TestModel obj= new TestModel();
                obj.setName(product.getName());
                newList.add(obj);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        //update ui here
                        // display toast here
                        Toast.makeText(TimeTable.this, "Not Null "+ newList.size()+""+obj.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TimeTable.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading----");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        //here i am getting error
        adapter=new TimeTableAdapter(newList,getApplicationContext());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter code,

```
public class TimeTableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimeTableAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<TestModel> list;
    Activity activity;

    public TimeTableAdapter(ArrayList<TestModel> list, Activity activity) {
        this.list = list;
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post that too?

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()` :)

Comment: You can also use `TimeTable.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Thanks.. TimeTable.this work for me

Answer (score -1):

Try using `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. Your code should look like:

```
adapter = new TimeTableAdapter(newList, getActivity());
```

Explanation:

You're probably getting an error because your constructor goes like:

```
public TimeTableAdapter(ArrayList<TestModel> list, Activity activity) {
    this.list = list;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

It needs your ArrayList of objects as well as an *activity*. However, in your fragment, you go with:

```
adapter = new TimeTableAdapter(newList, getApplicationContext());
```

What you are giving it is NOT an activity but your fragment class. This gives off an error (I forgot which one) because you're giving it a fragment class instead of an activity class. Hence, you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.